# Ethereum web3 - Running multiple instance of web3 httpprovider

Tags: ethereum

My question is how you can run two instances of the httpprovider? I tried the code below, but this doesn't work as only the first httpProvider is instantiated.

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9998"), new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9999"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want two instances of an HttpProvider. But I think a solution could be to not instantiate two providers but two web3 objects, e.g., like that:

```
let Web3 = require('web3');
let web3 = {};
let web3.a = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9998");
let web3.b = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9999");
```

And for whatever you need, you either use your provider `.a` or `.b`:

```
window.console.log(web3.a.version.node);
window.console.log(web3.b.version.node);
```

Or check which one is connected:

```
if(web3.a.isConnected()) {
    /* work with node a */
else if(web3.b.isConnected()) {
    /* work with node b */
} else {
    /* remind yourself to start a node */
}
```

The code above is untested, but you may get the idea.